# What did Evangelist Luke mean by 'many' in his introductory statement?

Tags: luke

We see the introductory paragraph of the Gospel according to Luke, as follows:

> Since many have undertaken to set down an orderly account of the events that have been fulfilled among us,
>
> Luke 1 - NRSV

Given that the Catholic Church recognizes , as Canonical, only three Gospels other than the one  according to Luke, the phrase "many have undertaken" as used by Luke sounds to be out of place, in that he could have used "a few". I wish to know what the exact word corresponding to the English "many" as used by Luke in the original text was, and what the interpretations of that word are.

Comment: The Greek word is πολλοὶ (polloi) - an indefinite number.  There were and still are many gospel accounts as Luke correctly notes.  Only Four have been recognised as canonical.  Is it possible to refine this question a little?

Comment: I have modified the question. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see much difference.  Are you thinking about Luke sources and that some were not canonical?  All readily admit that he (and many other Bible writers) used non-canonical sources.

Comment: Writings a Gospel account, and writing an inspired one, are not the same thing. Not all accounts of Jesus' life will be God-breathed.

Comment: This is only a guess, but I think "many" is intended to emphasize that Luke gathered a lot of material from a lot of sources. Additionally, it could possibly be an acknowledgement that some of what we now classify as non-canonical gospels were already starting to appear.

Comment: But we would have to assume that all these texts were lost or undiscovered, since no other Gospel account besides the 4 dates to 1st century, which would be at the time of Luke's writing.

Comment: And it says that "many have undertaken to 'compile a narrative'" or to 'draw up an account,' which indicates they recorded the events of what happened. That doesn't sound at all like he was saying Luke drew on "many non-canonical sources" or Luke interviewed "many witnesses." He seems to be talking about others writing up similar accounts, accounts written in 1st century before Luke's Gospel, which we currently have no idea what happened to them since I don't think we can identify them.

Answer (score 2):

The prevailing view (not unchallenged) among both critical and pious scholars is that Luke was the last of the synoptic gospels to be written. In other words he wrote after Mark and Matthew but prior to John. This is based on the so-called Markan priority view of the [synoptic problem](https://catholic-resources.org/Bible/Synoptic_Problem.htm) according to which both Luke and Matthew used an existing version of Mark plus the sayings source "Q" and their own particular other material. Presuming that this is correct, when Luke spoke of "many others," he referred to Mark and possibly Matthew, as well any unknown other accounts and legends he may have been aware of, but which have since been lost.

Whether he referred to Matthew, however, is debatable, because they wrote at roughly the same time. He may or may not have known of Matthew's Gospel. Other accounts he may have known of include:

- The [Gospel of the Hebrews](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Gospel_of_the_Hebrews)
- The [Gospel of the Ebionites](https://www.earlychristianwritings.com/gospelebionites.html).
- The [Gospel of Thomas](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Gospel_of_Thomas). Several scholars think Thomas was written prior to Luke, although this is by no means the consensus view.
- [Sayings Source Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_source). Both Matthew Luke included many saying from this hypothetical source in their work. It apparently once stood on its own, and Luke may have thought of it among his "orderly accounts."
- Nativity and infancy stories. Several such narratives were probably circulating, one of which (centering on Joseph rather than Mary) was included by Matthew but not Luke. In this category we may also include infancy and boyhood narratives such as the one Luke tells of Jesus in Lk. 2, about the presentation in the temple and the boy Jesus teaching the elders. Some of these stories seem to have found their way into later works such as the [Infancy Gospel of James](https://www.earlychristianwritings.com/infancyjames.html) and the [Infancy Gospel of Thomas](http://gnosis.org/library/inftoma.htm).
- Resurrection accounts. Even the canonical gospels give varying details about this important issue, and later apocryphal gospels go further. Luke may have referred to a wide variety of such legends, thinking that his work would provide clarity to his readership.
- Other Acts. Finally, since Luke and Acts are generally considered as being written by the same author, the prologue to Luke could refer to apocryphal or lost "acts" as well as gospels. In other words, "the events that have been fulfilled among us" could mean of works done by the various apostles, including collected miracle stories and martyrdom accounts.

**Conclusion: By "many" Luke could have meant what we would call "several." He probably referred to Mark and possibly Matthew. But since even "several" is more than two, it is probable that he was also thinking of other early gospels, birth narratives, infancy stories, resurrection accounts, apostolic acts, and collections of sayings of which he was aware but which are now lost.**

Answer (score 0):

The following is the definition of the word translated as many according to Strong’s dictionary. I have taken the liberty of including Luke chapter 1 verse 1 from many copies of different Bible translations that I have on my computer.

It should be noted that Luke a Gentile; was a constant companion to Paul, and as such he had the opportunity to interview many of the Apostles and possibly Mary (mother of Jesus ) as well as several other eye witnesses of Jesus life.
G4183
πολύς, πολλός
polus    polos
pol-oos'
Including the forms from the alternate “pollos”; (singular) much (in any respect) or (plural) many; neuter (singular) as adverb largely; neuter (plural) as adverb or noun often, mostly, largely: - abundant, + altogether, common, + far (passed, spent), (+ be of a) great (age, deal, -ly, while), long, many, much, oft (-en [-times]), plenteous, sore, straitly. Compare G4118, G4119.
Total KJV occurrences: 365

> (Bishops)  Forasmuche as manye haue taken in hande, to set foorth in order, ye declaration of those thynges whiche are moste surelye to be beleued among vs,
>   (Geneva)  Forasmuch as many haue taken in hand to set foorth the storie of those things, whereof we are fully persuaded,
>   (Hebrew NT DD)  אחרי אשר רבים הואילו לחבר ספור המעשים אשר נאמנו בשלמות בתוכנו׃
>   (Hebrew NT SG)  הֵן יְדֵי רַבִּים כָּתְבוּ עַל־סֵפֶר אֶת־מַעַרְכֵי הַדְּבָרִים אֲשֶׁר כּוֹנְנוּ בְתוֹכֵנוּ אֶל־נָכוֹן׃
>   (ISV)  Since many people have attempted to write an orderly account of the events that have transpired among us,
>   (KJV)  Forasmuch as many have taken in hand to set forth in order a declaration of those things which are most surely believed among us,
>   (KJV+)  ForasmuchG1895 as manyG4183 have taken in handG2021 to set forth in orderG392 a declarationG1335 ofG4012 those thingsG4229 which are most surely believedG4135 amongG1722 us,G2254
>   (KJV-1611)  Forasmuch as many haue taken in hande to set foorth in order a declaration of those things which are most surely beleeued among vs,
>   (KJVA)  Forasmuch as many have taken in hand to set forth in order a declaration of those things which are most surely believed among us,
>   (KJV-BRG)  Forasmuch as many have taken in hand to set forth in order a declaration of those things which are most surely believed among us,
>   (MKJV)  Since many took in hand to draw up an account concerning the matters which have been borne out among us,
>   (WEB)  Since many have undertaken to set in order a narrative concerning those matters which have been fulfilled among us,
>   (WEBA)  Since many have undertaken to set in order a narrative concerning those matters which have been fulfilled among us,
>   (YLT)  Seeing that many did take in hand to set in order a narration of the matters that have been fully assured among us,

If you find this insufficient please let me know and I will expound further.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. What does Luke mean by "many," and how does that work with there only being 3 other Gospel accounts that we are aware of in the 1st century?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ἐπειδήπερ (Partπειδήπερ) denotes the fact, assumed as known, common
   in literary Attic.

.

2. The Greek verb ἐπεχείρησαν (ἐπιχειρέω), means to undertake
   something, with a good or bad ending, completing or not, to fulfill
   the purpose that each one proposes.  It is most often used with the
   ideia of Annihilation, to destroy something completely so that
   nothing is left. 2 Chr. 20:11; 1 Es. 1:26; Ezr. 7:23; Est. 8:12;
   9:25; 2 Ma. 2:29; 7:19; 9:2; 10:15; 3 Ma. 6:24; 7:5; 4 Ma. 1:5; Lk.
   1:1; Acts 9:29; 19:13.

.

3. Αναταξασθαι, the word is composed of  τασσω, a common verb for
   arranging things in proper order and  ανα, again. “The expression
   points to a connected series of narratives in some order [τᾰ́ξῐς],
   topical or chronological rather than to isolated narratives” (Bruce)

.

4. διήγησιν (διήγησις), a narration—history. The word is clearly
   explained in Plato, Rep. iii. p. 392: ἆρʼ οὐ πάντα ὅσα ὑπὸ μυθολόγων
   ἢ ποιητῶν λέγεται, διήγησις οὖσα τυγχάνει ἢ γεγονότων ἢ ὄντων ἢ
   μελλόντων; τί γάρ, ἔφη, ἄλλο; ἆρα οὖν οὐχὶ ἤτοι ἁπλῇ διηγήσει ἢ διὰ
   μιμήσεως γιγνομένῃ ἢ διʼ ἀμφοτέρων περαίνουσιν: THE GREEK
   TESTAMENTAN EXEGETICAL AND CRITICAL COMMENTARY Volume II: Luke–John
   HENRY ALFORD, Jda. 7:15; Jdg. 5:14; 2 Ma. 2:32; 6:17; Sir. 6:35;
   9:15; 22:6; 27:11, 13; 38:25; 39:2; Hab. 2:6; Lk. 1:1 see “Let these
   words suffice for recalling this truth. Without further ado we must
   go on with our story”. 2 Maccabees 6:17 NABRE

.

5. This word "many" must have the value of "some" Martin Franz Dibelius
   . Lk. 1:1, 14, 16; 2:34-36; 3:13, 18; 4:25, 27, 41; 5:6, 15, 29;
   6:17, 23, 35; 7:11, 21, 42-43, 47; 8:3-4, 29-30; 9:13, 22, 37; 10:2,
   24, 40-41; 11:31-32, 53; 12:7, 19, 23, 47-48; 13:24; 14:16, 25;
   15:13; 16:10; 17:25; 18:39; 21:3, 8, 27; 22:65; 23:27; Jn. 2:12, 23;
   3:23; 4:1, 39, 41; 5:6; 6:2, 5, 10, 60, 66; 7:12, 31; 8:26, 30;
   10:20, 32, 41-42; 11:19, 45, 47, 55; 12:9, 11-12, 24, 42; 14:2, 30;
   15:2, 5, 8; 16:12; 19:20; 20:30; 21:15, 25; In special Lk 4:41;
   5:29; 8:30 (many  = legion = 500); 9:13.

.

6. Περι, around, an investigative historian about those events as well
   as an eye-witness to what immediately followed.

.
.
** "*Many*" preceded Luke in writing gospels, and these were discrepant; Lucas did historical work to destroy them.**

Answer (score 0):

Luke is probably referring here to numerous false gospels that seemed to have been circulating.  We might note that he writes *many have undertaken to set down* rather than simply *many have set down*.

This was explained in the Byzantine commentary on Luke by Theophlyact:

> Who were these *many* who *attempted to set forth in order an account*?  The false apostles.  For there were many who wrote so-called "gospels," for example, "The gospel according to the Egyptians," and "The gospel of the twelve."  But these false apostles only attempted to set forth; they did not finish and perfect their narratives because they began without divine grac.  Luke therefore says well that *many have attempted*.  Only a few, such as Matthew and Mark, not only attempted to set forth, but finished and perfected their narrative.  For they had the Holy Spirit, Which perfects.